# Is there a Time Corrected Velocity Verlet algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, math, integral

I know of Velocity Verlet which doesn't have the initialisation issue of Verlet and has velocity calculation in it's workings, and Time Corrected Verlet which is correct for varying timesteps but doesn't include velocity calculations . I would like something like a "Time Corrected Velocity Verlet" which incorporates velocity calculations like Velocity Verlet and is correct with varying timesteps like Time-Corrected Verlet. Is this a well known algorithm I can find somewhere? I havn't found it on stackoverflow or google.

Comment: You say you know A and B, but you'd like something like C. Could you clearly define what is the difference between B and C? At least to me, it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Edited to be more clear (hopefully)

Comment: Much better! <padding>

Comment: What is preventing you from changing the time step in every velocity-Verlet step? As you mentioned, the velocities are consistent at each time step.

Comment: You are right I've looked at the algorithm and done tests Verlet Velocity isn't wrong with varying timesteps. When I read Verlet was, I assumed Velocity Verlet must be as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time Corrected Velocity Verlet is Velocity Verlet. Looking at Velocity Verlet and it's derivation one can see it isn't wrong with varying timesteps. One can also test this with a simple system and a variable timestep. Time-Corrected Verlet and Velocity Verlet yield similar solutions.

I was convinced Velocity Verlet had to be wrong with varying timesteps if Verlet was. But it turns out those algorithms are more different than the names would suggest.